# Move to chosen record in datasheet subform based on current record in main form MS Access

Tags: ms-access, subform

I have a form that is meant to change records or add new ones. On the same form I have subform datasheet of the same table so I can look at all the other records besides the one I am changing/creating. I would like the two (form and subform) to connect in a way, that when I for example move to 5th record in the datasheet subform, that record would be shown in my main form automatically.
At the moment I have it all set in a way, that when I lets say start a new record in my main form, data is automatically updated in the datasheet too, and that is when I change any field in the main form. That way I have live data in both, main and subform - I've done that via

```
Private Sub Field1_AfterUpdate()
Me.Refresh
End Sub
```

for every field. And that means that whenever I change any field in my main form, in my subform datasheet the first record automatically becomes in focus because of that refresh.

[Form and DatasheetSubform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uv5Yb.png)

Any suggestions how to fix that?

Comment: This is emulating a Split form. Did you try the Split form model?

Comment: @June7 Thank you for your suggestion. I haven't thought of that so I will try it out and post about it.

Comment: as @june7 suggested, Split form was the answer.